# Vector3 vs. Vector2 - performance, usage?

Tags: xna, xna-4.0, performance, vector

I'm currently playing around with XNA, and creating a simple 2D platformer. I was thinking of adding multiple layers to make it a little bit of challenge.

In stead of having a `Vector2` for my positions, I now use a `Vector3`, solely to use it's `Z` as layer depth. However, since you can't use operators between `Vector2` and `Vector3` for some unknown reason **[1]**, I ended up changing all other `Vector2`s in my game, such as *acceleration*, *speed* and *offset*, so I can do things like `position +=  offset` without errors.

I also changed my rotation variable from `float` to `Vector3`, and I use the `Z` value to rotate my textures. I'm planning to use the `X` and `Y` to scale-flip my textures, so you get the Super Paper Mario effect.

However, after changing all these `Vector2`s in `Vector3`s, I felt a little bad about it. How does this effect the performance of games? I know I shouldn't have to worry about performance in my little platformer game, but I'm just curious about it.

Is there any notable performance between `Vector2`s and `Vector3`s, for example when adding or multiplying them, or when calling `Normalize`, `Transform`, or `Distance`?

---

**[1]** Just a side question, why are there no operators for calculations between Vector3 and Vector2?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

> Is there any notable performance between `Vector2`s and `Vector3`s, for example when adding or multiplying them, or when calling `Normalize`, `Transform`, or `Distance`?

Yes, you have one more coordinate so you will use more CPU cycles.

But it is very unlikely that it will ever give you any trouble. [XNA 4 is using SIMD extensions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb417503.aspx#ID4E4F) for vector math (EDIT: [**on Windows Phone only**](http://xboxforums.create.msdn.com/forums/p/86655/520695.aspx)), so the implementation is very optimal (on that platform). Except if you're doing very heavy computing, it is very unlikely to ever cause you trouble. You do need `Vector3`s for your positions because you're now doing 3D (or 2.5D...), so please don't do any premature optimization. This is **97% evil**<sup>1</sup>.

> Just a side question, why are there no operators for calculations
>   between Vector3 and Vector2?

Because it makes no sense, mathematically. What would you expect to come out from such calculations? For instance what should happen if you try to add a `Vector3` and a `Vector2`:

[*x1, y1, z1*] + [*x2, y2*] = [*x1 + x2, y1 + y2, z1*] **or** [*x1, y1 + x2, z1 + y2*] ?

In this case, you'll typically need to determine by yourself what you want as a third coordinate for the `Vector2`, and where you wish to add it. For instance this solves the ambiguity:

[*x1, y1, z1*] + [*x2, y2,* **0**] = [*x1 + x2, y1 + y2, z1*]

---

Now it's possible that some parts of your gameplay work only in 2D. If there are cases where you only need 2D coordinates, and if the computing *does* get really heavy (e.g. 2D physics), you can stick to `Vector2`s in that specific part of the code to save some precious cycles. You can then easily switch between 2D and 3D coordinates when you need to (e.g. get a scene position from a 2D physics position, or the other way around):

E.g. from `Vector2` to `Vector3` using [this constructor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb195788%28v=xnagamestudio.40%29.aspx):

```
Vector2 v2;
Vector3 v3(v2, someDepthValue);
```

Or from `Vector3` to `Vector2` using [that constructor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb195795.aspx);

```
Vector3 v3;
Vector2 v2(v3.X, v3.Y);
```

---

<sup>1</sup>In [Donald Knuth's words](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?PrematureOptimization):

> Programmers waste enormous amounts of time thinking about, or worrying
>   about, the speed of noncritical parts of their programs, and these
>   attempts at efficiency actually have a strong negative impact when
>   debugging and maintenance are considered. We should forget about small
>   efficiencies, say about 97% of the time: **premature optimization is the
>   root of all evil**. Yet we *should* not pass up our opportunities in that
>   critical 3%.

Comment: Like I said, I know I don't have to worry about performance so soon, but it was just my curiosity that made me post this question. I guess you're right about the *ambiguity*. Thanks for the clear answer :)

Comment: @RuudLenders I've added details on how you could proceed if you ever face performance issues.

Comment: I've edited your answer to include a *very* important point: SIMD is only used by XNA on Windows Phone! The .NET runtime on PC - and therefore XNA itself - does not support SIMD. The equivalent is also not supported on Xbox 360.

Comment: (On PC and Xbox 360, [Understanding XNA Framework Performance](http://www.microsoft.com/en-au/download/details.aspx?id=16477) is still the applicable guide for optimising your vector operations.)

Comment: Premature optimisation is not evil. Only useless premature optimisation is. You need to rule it out on the grounds of being *useless*, not on the grounds of being premature.

Comment: @SamHocevar Well, I guess this is a matter of definitions. To me premature optimization is optimizing without metrics on performance, so without knowledge of usefulness. This was a reference to Donald Knuth's quote: "premature optimization is the root of all evil".

Comment: @LaurentCouvidou Well I don’t think that’s what Knuth meant by premature. Premature only means *before the usually moment*, and about 97% of the people forget to mention that Knuth’s full quote starts with “97 percent of the time”. (by the way I agree with your answer, just not with that specific use of the quote).

Comment: @SamHocevar Fair enough, then let's say it's around 97% evil :) Edited!

Answer (score 3):

You're trying to optimize prematurely. Most of the operations you mentioned ( normalize, transform, distance ) are pretty much identical to what vector2D does, if you can look at their code you will notice that they are practically the same. The only difference is that vector3D has a third axis. Performance wise it should be trivial compared to a Vector2D.

As for your side question:
 Because you can't multiply matrixes/row-vectors/column-vectors that both have different sizes.

Answer (score 1):

One of the biggest performance effects of using `Vector3` unnecessarily, instead of `Vector2`, is the 50% increase in size and **the effect that has on cache**.

That unnecessary extra data needs to be loaded into the CPU cache from main memory. This is *sloooow*.

In addition, by loading in this unnecessary data, you increase the chance that you are pushing out *useful* data that then immediately has to be loaded *back into* cache.

In a modestly tight loop, the cache effects will overwhelm any CPU effects of doing extra operations.

Also, it's faster to add the elements directly (due to various quirks of .NET). So if you're micro-optimising you won't be using the vector operations anyway. So if you only need to add the first two elements of a vector, you could do this:

```
v1.X += v2.X; v1.Y += v2.Y;
```

But these kinds of performance considerations are only really applicable to things like particle engines, physics engines, and so on. So don't worry too much!

Comment: So is manual inlining still the fastest way to go even with the added support of SIMD?

Comment: @MikaelHögström SIMD *is* almost certainly going to be faster - but it is *only* available on the Windows Phone platform (see the edit and comments I made to Laurent Couvidou's answer).